# Custom EditorFor and ICollection issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm doing this

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var g = new MyGroup
    {
        Caracteristicas = db.Caracteristicas.ToList()
    };
    return View(g);
}
```

and getting this exception when trying to display that data:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Caracteristicas)
```

Custom editor:

```
@model Exemplo.Models.Caracteristica
<label class="checkbox">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Valor) @Model.Nome</label>
```

**SOLVED (in part)**

The problem was that I mismatched the name of the custom editor file.

But now that this little mistake is fixed, however, all `Id`s (in bind) are zero... how to solve that? :(

This is the output:

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Valor field is required." id="Caracteristicas_0__Valor" name="Caracteristicas[0].Valor" type="checkbox" value="true" />
  <input name="Caracteristicas[0].Valor" type="hidden" value="false" />
  OldItem</label>
```

"value" shouldn't be the Id? :(

Comment: your custom editor should be a iteration on collection, because you are passing a list to it. please check that.

Comment: @HaBo - i updated the editor up there. That still doesnt work. :(

Comment: i put a breakpoint inside the custom editor, but it isnt even entering there. The error is on the line `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Caracteristicas)`

Comment: you are getting ID id="Caracteristicas_0__Valor"